# In python, how do you loop a dictionary but keep the changes made to it

Tags: python-3.x

So basically im new to python and programming in general.  I was wondering say you have a situation where you have a dictionary and are asking the user if they want to add or delete terms in the dictionary.  So I know how to add or delete the term in dictionaries but how do "save" that data for the next time the program starts.  Basically, if the user added a word to the dictionary and then I asked them if they wanted to return to the main menu using a while loop, how would you make it so the word they added is now permanently in the dictionary when he returns to the menu and starts the program over?

Here is what I had.  Mind you I'm a beginner and so if it looks weird, then sorry...lol....nothing serious:

```
loop=None
while True:
    #The initial dictionary
    things={"house":"a place where you live",
            "computer":"you use to do lots of stuff",
            "iPod":"mp3 player",
            "TV":"watch shows on it",
            "bed":"where you sleep",
            "wii":"a game system",
            "pizza":"food"}


    #Menu
    print("""

        Welcome to the Dictionary of Things
            Choose your preference:

        0-Quit
        1-Look up a Term
        2-Add a Term
        3-Redefine a Term
        4-Delete a Term

        """)

    choice=input("\nWhat do you want to do?: ")

elif choice=="2": #Adds a term for the user
        term=input("What term do you want to add? ")
        if term not in things:
            definition=input("Whats the definition? ")
            things[term]=definition #adds the term to the dictionary
            print(term,"has been added to the dictionary")
            menu=input("""
                    Would you like to go back to the menu?
                            Yes(Y) or No(N):  """)
                if menu=="Y":
                    loop=None  ----->#Ok so if they want to go back to the menu the program should remember what they added
                elif menu=="N":
                    break
```

Comment: Showing code where you demonstrate the problem you are having helps you get more useful answers.

Comment: ok i'll add it but it probably wont be pretty

Comment: Excellent! I've updated my answer. But before you look, ask yourself "What is the first thing that happens when you go to the beginning of the loop".

Comment: lol....now i see it, i didnt even realize it created a new dictionary everytime it looped.

Comment: @david: your question is misleading.  Expressions like "start the program over", "save until next time program starts" and "permanently in the dictionary" hint at object serialization (hence all the replies about json and pickle), whereas all you wanted to do is make sure that data stays in the dictionary between function calls.  Glad you worked things out, though.

Comment: im sorry, i probably should have phrased it differently.  thank u for the help tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

Your problem is that you redefine the dictionary at the start of each loop. Move the start definition of the dictionary to before the While loop, and you are in business.

---

Dictionaries and lists are mutable objects. Hence, if it is modified in a  function, it stays modified where it was called too:

```
def main_function():
    do someting
    mydict = {'a': 2, 'b': 3}
    subfunction(mydict)
    print mydict

def otherfunction(thedict):
    dict['c'] = 5
```

If you now run main_function, it will print out a dictionary that includes 'c'.

Answer (score 1):

As misha already said, pickle is a good idea, but an easier way is to use the [shelve](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/shelve.html) module,which uses (c)pickle internally and does exactly what you ask for. 
From the docs:

```
import shelve

d = shelve.open(filename) # open

d[key] = data   # store data at key (overwrites old data if
                # using an existing key)
data = d[key]   # retrieve a COPY of data at key (raise KeyError if no
                # such key)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might help to be more specific about the structure of your program.  It sounds like you want to persist a dictionary as an external file, to be loaded/reloaded on subsequent runs of your app.  In this case you could use the pickle library like so:

```
import pickle
dictionary = {"foo": "bar", "spam": "egg"}

# save it to a file...
with open("myfile.dct", "wb") as outf:
    pickle.dump(dictionary, outf)

# load it in again:
reloaded = {}
with open("myfile.dct", "rb") as inf:
    reloaded = pickle.load(inf)
```

Comment: o_0.....oh lord....ok these responses are helpful im just confused cuz im so new to programming.  Ok so essentially I would have to save the dictionary to a file and then reload it? So once the user adds or deletes a term I should save that and when the program restarts it should bring back the dictionary w/ the new information.

Comment: @david: If you with "restart" mean that the program exits and you then start it again, then yes, you must save the data to a file. It's no different from Word or a gem etc. If changes are not saved, then yes, they are not saved.
If you with "restart" mean that you go back to the main menu (as your question indicates) then no, you don't have to save anything.

Comment: yeah i mean restart as in the person is still in the program but it loops back to the main menu.  Everytime the program loops back to the beginning how do you make it so the data they entered is now in the dictionary when it originally wasn't there the 1st time.  I added the code too